# How do I get notification first on active device?

Tags: macos, iphone, messages

I hear my iPhone chime upon the arrival of a notification. Minutes later it shows up on my Mac, even when I am working actively on the Mac.

Is there a way to tell the notification to arrive on the device with the active screen first?

I got similar issue with FaceTime. The request comes first to the device I'm not using currently.

Hardware:

- Mac Pro 2012 running OS X Yosemite
- iPhone 6 running iOS 12.1

Comment: Notifications normally come to the device last used. Is it not doing that?

Comment: No.  It's not doing that.